# Get object from another class in component react

Tags: reactjs

Good morning,
I'm new to react, and I'm trying to figure things out.
I found a spotify button which connect to the spotify API from your `cliendID`. It looks like this

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import SpotifyLogin from 'react-spotify-login';
import { clientId, redirectUri } from './settings';

const onSuccess = response => console.log(response);
const onFailure = response => console.error(response);

ReactDOM.render(
  <SpotifyLogin clientId={clientId}
    redirectUri={redirectUri}
    onSuccess={onSuccess}
    onFailure={onFailure}/>,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

The data I want to get is the `response` from it because it has the `access_token`. Being new to react, I thought I could make a class with a getter in it.

```js
import React, { Component, setState, useState } from 'react';
import SpotifyLogin from 'react-spotify-login';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            onSuccess : {}
        }
    }

    getData() {
        return this.onSuccess;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <SpotifyLogin buttonText="Login" clientId='myinfo'
                    redirectUri='http://localhost:3000/home'
                    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

but in my other component, when I try to do a

```js
var toto = new App
console.log(toto.getData);
```

it's all empty. Moreover, I would like to know if there's a way which will allow me to avoid the declaration of a new object inside my component each time I will need to access my data. For example, I will pass `props` to my classes, so if I call this component in the file where I declared an instance of `App` it will be ok, but what if I use this component in another file and there's no instance of `App`, how could I have access to this data. Is there a way to `global` it ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your class component is going to have `this.onSuccess` return empty as it is never being set. Since you have changed `this.onSuccess` to a state variable, you need to set that state at some point. Currently, your `onSuccess` function in your render will not work because it is not a function at all.

So instead you would need to change the response state before `getData` is going to work, for example:

```js
import React, { Component, setState, useState } from 'react';
import SpotifyLogin from 'react-spotify-login';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            responseObject : {}
        }
    }

    onSuccess(response) {
        this.setState({ responseObject: response}) 
    }

    getData() {
        return this.responseObject;
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <SpotifyLogin buttonText="Login" clientId='myinfo'
                    redirectUri='http://localhost:3000/home'
                    onSuccess={this.onSuccess}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App
```

Although, as to your second question, it would make more sense to define this `onSuccess` function in a higher class, and pass that function down through props like you suggested, so that you do not have to use the `getData` function at all. So instead you could just do:

```js
class SpotifyContainer extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <SpotifyLogin buttonText="Login" clientId='myinfo'
                    redirectUri='http://localhost:3000/home'
                    onSuccess={this.props.onSuccess}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and therefore you can just pass `onSuccess` down as a function with props.

Personally I would recommend using React Hooks / Functional components as well, as I find they can be somewhat easier to understand than class components, especially if you are not going to be using state. So you could instead just write:

```js
function SpotifyContainer(props) {
    return (
            <div>
                <Link to="/home">
                    <SpotifyLogin buttonText="Login" clientId='myinfo'
                    redirectUri='http://localhost:3000/home'
                    onSuccess={props.onSuccess}/>
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
}

export default SpotifyContainer;
```